# Selenium will not select drop down option due to visibility issues

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**UPDATED**
*In my Django settings, when I set DEBUG to false, Selenium is able to interact with the elements. It still does not work when DEBUG is set to true*

So I am trying to select one option in a dropdown menu, but when I try to directly access the `<select>` tag I get the error `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable`.

In the console whenever I click on the dropdown in only refers to an input tag that dynamically changes based on what I click on. Ultimately, I want the test to click on the dropdown and then select 'Tango' as shown in the link below.

[image: click here]

**My Selenium code is:**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost:8000/")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-dance"]').click())

select.select_by_value('1')
```

**And HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
 <div class="row border-light bg-white rounded-left rounded-right no-gutters">
 <div class="col-12 col-lg px-3">
     <div class="select-wrapper mdb-select">
     <span class="caret"></span>
     <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-20f378f1-9560-4598-b8e8- 
    3ffe496cd688" value="Choose your dance event">
<ul id="select-options-20f378f1-9560-4598-b8e8-3ffe496cd688" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 658px; position:absolute;top: 0px; left: 0px;opacity: 1; display: none;">
<li class="">
  <span class="filtrable">Choose your dance event</span></li>
<li class="">
  <span class="filtrable">Tango</span></li>
<li class="active selected">
  <span class="filtrable">Swing</span>
</li>
<li class="">
  <span class="filtrable">Latin/Salsa</span>
</li>
<li class="">
  <span class="filtrable">Ballroom</span>
</li>
<li class="">
  <span class="filtrable">Bachata</span>
</li>
</ul>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="select-dance">


   <option value="0">Choose your dance event</option>

   <option value="1">Tango</option>

   <option value="2">Swing</option>

   <option value="3">Latin/Salsa</option>

   <option value="4">Ballroom</option>

   <option value="5">Bachata</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I do not know how to deal with the input tag interfering with the select (it only shows up in the elements console in Chrome).
Thank you!

Comment: Do not pass `click` method call into `Select`. You need `select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-dance"]'))` or `select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select-dance'))`

Comment: Seems an invalid _HTML_, 3 starting `<div>` tags but 4 ending `<div>` tags. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle by,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost:8000/")

time.sleep(10)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select-dance'))
select.select_by_value('1')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work :( Literally copy and pasted this code and I receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost:8000/")

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_id('select-dance').click()
```

when you click then new list of s will get populated under , then call select tag

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select-dance'))
select.select_by_value('1')
```

or

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-dance"]'))
select.select_by_value('1')
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions! But I am still receiving the exact same error.  Any element I am asking for it to click in is apparently 'not interactable'

Comment: can you please provide full exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your page uses custom Select Component which is not the default [html select box](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select). In your case, they have used [MDBootstrap Select Component](https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/material-select/) which cannot be interacted using selenium `Select` class.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785630/selenium-tests-are-not-able-to-interact-with-any-of-the-elements/52788066#52788066) answer for your another question which related to the same issue.