# Selenium tests are not able to interact with any of the elements

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I know that when I have DEBUG in my Django settings set to False, Selenium fails to have access to the static files, resulting in something looking like:

[image: this]

However, when I run my Selenium tests regardless they are able to interact with the DOM and select items from the dropdown! The test code I have is currently

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost:8000/")

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('select-dance').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-dance"]'))
select.select_by_value('1')

driver.find_element_by_id('select-date-range').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-date-range"]')) 
select.select_by_value('1')

driver.find_element_by_id('location').click()
```

When I set DEBUG to True, the page renders how I want it to because it has access to the static files. But whenever I try to run the tests I always get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

[image: What the search bar looks like with all of the static files working]

This seems to happen for any element I refer to. For some reason, when I try to click on the dropdown directly, it always highlights this input and the select tag always seems to be 'hidden', so I wonder if that may be causing the error 
[image: See here]

Thank you all for your help, I don't know why Selenium is not being allowed to directly access the select tag for drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Your page uses custom Select Component which is not the default [html select box](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select). In your case, they have used [MDBootstrap Select Component](https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/material-select/) which cannot be interacted using selenium `Select` class

You are right. You are trying to interact with `<select>` dom which is not visible and it is throwing element not visible exception.
We have two automate this case exactly similar like the manual steps,

*i.e.,*

1. *Click the element which is intractable.*
2. *Wait for the dropdown appears.*
3. *Click the value from the dropdown.*

In your case for selecting first value in dance select box, the code can rewritten as below.

```
# this is click the input element which is intractable
# Here the input box which contains value 'dance event' is clicked

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.select-dropdown[value*="dance event"]').click  

# Then we are waiting for the first value of the dropdown which is not disabled

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.select-dropdown[value*="dance event"]+ul>li:not(.disabled)')))

# Click the element first value of the dropdown

element.click()
```