# how to select options from an "mdb-select" list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

So, I am trying to select an option from a list of type `mdb-select` using the following code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectEntidaBancaria")));

dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Davivienda S.A.");
```

But `Java` shows me the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "mdb-select"
```

What method could you use to select an option from that type of list?

Comment: Share HTML in text or URL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785630/selenium-tests-are-not-able-to-interact-with-any-of-the-elements/52788066#52788066 should help

Answer (score 0):

So because your list is not a standard select, Selenium Select fails. Instead, you should be able to do the following.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("selectEntidaBancaria")).click(); //click on the list to bring up choices

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//mdb-select[contains(.,'Davivienda S.A.')]")); //wait for dropdown to appear and be clickable

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mdb-select[contains(.,'Davivienda S.A.')]")).click(); // and click on it
```

adapted from Python answer at [Selenium tests are not able to interact with any of the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785630/selenium-tests-are-not-able-to-interact-with-any-of-the-elements/52788066#52788066)